# Explicit quasi-inverse of Künneth-isomorphism?

Tags: homology-cohomology, inverse, differential-forms

With $A_X$ the complex of $\mathbb{R}$-differential forms on $X$, the Künneth theorem states that 
\begin{align*}
A_X \otimes  A_Y &\to A_{X \times Y}, \\
(\omega,\eta) &\mapsto {\rm pr}_X^\ast \omega \wedge {\rm pr}_Y^\ast \eta
\end{align*}
gives an isomorphism on cohomology. 
Is there any explicit formula describing a quasi-inverse of this map? I.e. a map 
$$ A_{X\times Y} \to A_X \otimes A_Y $$ 
inducing an inverse on cohomology groups ?

Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, even if a canonically defined map happens to be invertible, there won't be a nice way to describe the inverse. For example, already the inverse of the map $V \to V^{\ast \ast}$ from a finite-dimensional vector space to its double dual doesn't have a nice description (somehow, if it did, it wouldn't be sensitive to the fact that $V$ is finite-dimensional).